# World sports with leagues and teams

Tags: sports

I'm trying to find a simple json or xml (not feed) containing all sports. sport leagues and league teams around the world (or at least some sports)

I can't seem to find such a file

Comment: I assume http://sportsdatabase.com/ was unhelpful?